# Text not surrounding floating image on iPhone

Tags: html, iphone, css, fluid-layout

I created a fluid css for mobile devices. Here is my website [Click here](http://www.conradchamerski.com)

For a small width the css changes, you can see it from your browser by decreasing the witdh. The problem is that, on google chrome my text surrounds the image well, but when I visit the page from my iPhone, the text goes below the img. Is the float property not working well on iOS?

**Mobile CSS**

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
/* remember to highlight inserts somehow! */
ins {
    text-decoration: none;
}
del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/*!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Style BEGINS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*/
body {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    line-height: 120%;
   font-weight: 300;
    color: black;
    list-style:none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
h1
{
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 200%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

h2
{
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin-bottom:5px;

}
h3
{
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 75%;
}
/*Wrapper of the whole mobile website*/
#wrapper
{   
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
}

/*Top buttons*/
#top_buttons
{
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
}
#top_buttons a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: grey solid 1px;
}

#top_buttons li:last-child
{
    border: none;
}
#paperbox
{
position:relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

#main_sliding_pictures
{
float:right;
margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#textwrapper
{
    padding: 15px 5px 5px 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}


.slider {
float:right;
  margin: 15px 5px 5px 25px;
  width: 183px; /* Update to your slider width */
  height: 183px; /* Update to your slider height */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
            box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}

.slider li {
  display: none;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
}


#icons
{
    float:bottom;
}


#icons li
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;    
}

#icons a
{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#goUp
{
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#goUp a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=320">
        <title>Home page</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="Homepage">
        <meta name="description" content="Homepage">
        <meta name="author" content="Conrad Chamerski">
        <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px)' href='css/narrow.css' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px)' href='css/narrow.css' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 769px)' href='css/wide.css' />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


</script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <nav id="top_buttons">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Pages/Projects.html">Project</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Pages/Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav><!--end primary_nav-->

        <div id="paperbox" class="boxcontainer">
            <div id="main_sliding_pictures">
    <ul class="slider">
        <li>
   <img src="images/maface.jpeg" height="183px" width="183px" />
 </li>
 <li>
   <img src="images/ProjectPictures/elwirebike.jpg" height="183px" width="183px" />
 </li>
 <li>
   <img src="images/ProjectPictures/monitor2.jpg" height="183px" width="183px" alt="HELLO"/>
 </li>
 <li>
   <img src="images/ProjectPictures/projectsmall3.png" height="183px" width="183px" align="ITS WORKING!!!" />
 </li>
</ul>
            </div>

            <div id="textwrapper">
                <h1>
                    About me
                </h1>
                <h2>
                    Prospective electrical engineer from Concordia University. My educational interests span from programming to electronics. My hobbies are sports, technology and philosophy.
                </h2>
                <div id="rating"></div>
            </div><!--end textwrapper-->

            <div id="icons">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="mailto:conradchamerski@gmail.com">
                    <img src="/images/logos/google.png" width="15px" height="15px">conradchamerski@gmail.com</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/conradchamerski/">
                    <img src="/images/logos/linkedin.png" width="15px" height="15px">Linkedin</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="https://twitter.com/ConradChamerski">
                    <img src="/images/logos/twitter.png" width="15px" height="15px">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/1631092/conrad-c">
                    <img src="/images/logos/stackoverflow.png" width="15px" height="15px">Stackoverflow</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--end icons-->



    </div><!--end paperbox-->
            <div id="goUp">
            <a href="#home">Top</a>
        </div><!--end goUp-->
  </div><!--end wrapper-->

    <!--<footer>Copyright Conrad Chamerski 2013 &#169;</footer>
    -->


    <script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works but the problem is that iphone screen is smaller 320 that breaks...

..In my opinion doing this will look better for your iOS iphone versions:

[image]

Wrapping the image on your iPhone will make it too obstrusive (too tight and ugly)...What I did here, is on media queries I gave the h1 (About Me)

@media="screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 320px):

```
#textwrapper h1  {clear: both; padding: 12px 0;}
```

and also for the image (**.slider**) I took the **float: right off and fixed the padding**

This to me works better and if you want to be even slicker you can make the image 100% and height auto so it can look better on iOS (up to you).

Comment: Thanks,

Do you know where can I learn about website aesthetics?

Comment: Theres a couple of places that have great articles on Responsive prototyping and look and feel. Some in names are: A List Apart, Web Designer Ledger, Smashing Magazine...I think getting an HTML5+CSS3 book is a great idea(Responsive). and lastly looking a grids for Responsive (Bootstrap, Foundation, etc)